# CORS: PHP bypass not working

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm working on a Chrome extension part of which is a function which manipulates images on a page using `canvas` and its `context.getImageData` function. That's when I ran into `CORS` issues. It's my understanding that a server serving an image has to server said image with appropriate `CORS` headers in order for cross-domain requests to be successful. I started reading up on this (to me) new and unfamiliar technology ([tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors)). A substantial number of servers doesn't employ `CORS` and it's very important for the function of my extension that **every** image is processed. I've spent a whole day trying to circumvent this issue using client-side scripting but came to the conclusion that the only way is to send the image url to a server and then serve it back **with** the needed `CORS` headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). Now before I get into explaining my implementation I'd like to quote a paragraph from the tutorial page I linked previously.

> Cross-Domain from Chrome Extensions
>
> Chrome extensions support cross-domain requests in a two different ways:
>
> Include domain in manifest.json - Chrome extensions can make cross-domain requests to any domain *if* the domain is included in the "permissions" section of the manifest.json file:
>
> > "permissions": [ "http://*.html5rocks.com"]
>
> The server doesn't need to include any additional CORS headers or do any more work in order for the request to succeed.

This should mean that `"permissions": "<all_urls>"` should circumvent same origin policy restrictions. However, this does not work.

### My solution

An `XMLHttpRequest` passes the image url and callback function to the server on localhost (*for testing purposes*) which first sets the appropriate header:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`,

and then prints a `JSON` encoded array containing image width, height,  and using `file_get_contents`, `imagecreatefromstring`, and `base64_encode`,  the equivalent of `context.getImageData` and a call to the callback function.

The callback function sets the src property of an `Image` Object (that has `crossOrigin` set to `Anonymous`) which is used for drawing the images onto the canvas and sets it's width and height properties.

### Result

The expected result was for every image to be loaded and processed without raising a `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy` error, **however** now every image seems to be served **without** the needed `CORS` headers crippling my extension. I checked the headers the page on localhost which processes this request sends and it seems to be okay. (*[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R21r0.png)*)

### Conclusion

My implementation of this solution *seems* like it should work and I really have no idea why it doesn't. The server is sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the image data is good and the callback function is called. This is the only issue left to resolve before release. This is a really intriguing issue. I realise the header I'm sending isn't the only one I might want to send but it's sufficient for testing purposes.

I hope this question was clear, and detailed enough for someone to help me resolve this issue. Please do not hesitate to ask for more information and/or code snippets as I didn't really include any code in an attempt to keep this concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image src is a data uri (base64 encoded image data), then there is no headers to set access control.

Just set the image source to the url you're calling in ajax and send back the image not encoded(`echo file_get_contents`).

Comment: you seem to have misunderstood me, I'm passing the _image url_ to the server and it sends back the _data uri_

Comment: I believe its the other way around(you misunderstood me). Do `img.src = 'http://localhost/dim-service/?url=https%3Aetc';`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I modified the scripts so the php only returns the data_uri and I'm setting the img.src to the response and it's still giving me the error.